# MVC - Manter PartialView carregada quando ModelState não é válida

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma tela de cadastro simples que, quando selecionado novo registro, é aberta uma modal (que é uma *partialview* no projeto) para o usuário informar os campos para cadastro.

A chamada à view é realizada através de Jquery:

```
$("#btn-Incluir").click(function () {
    $("#modalCadastro").modal({
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: true
    }, 'show');
});
```

O botão salvar da *PartialView* é do tipo `submit`, e dentro do meu *controller* tenho o método abaixo:

```
public virtual ActionResult Salvar(TViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (model.Operacao.Equals("I"))
                Inserir(model);
            else
                Atualizar(model);                

            return RedirectToAction(NmView);

        }
        else
        {
            return PartialView(model);
        }
    }
```

O problema é que quando a `ModalState` está inválida, é exibido erro abaixo:

> The partial view 'Salvar' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched

Se altero e retorno e passo o caminho da minha *partial view*, o sistema exibe apenas a *partial view*, não mais como modal filha da página principal.

Como faço para que quando o `ModalState` estiver inválido, continuar com a modal aberta e apenas apresentar os erros na página via `ValidationMessageFor`.

Obrigado!

Comment: Existe uma *PartialView* chamada `Salvar.cshtml` dentro do subdiretórios correspondente ao seu *Controller* que está dentro do diretório `Views`?

Comment: Não. O Salvar é apenas um método dentro do meu controller, que retorna um action result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há uma porção de más práticas aqui. Dentro do seu método `Salvar`, você tem:

```
public virtual ActionResult Salvar(TViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (model.Operacao.Equals("I"))
            Inserir(model);
        else
            Atualizar(model);                

        return RedirectToAction(NmView); // Isto muda o estado atual da página

    }
    else // Desnecessário
    {
        return PartialView(model); // Isto não necessariamente muda o estado atual da página.
    }
}
```

Além disso, você não tem uma *Partial* chamada `Salvar.cshtml`, o que ocasiona o erro.

Se a ideia do método `Salvar` é não modificar o estado atual da página, o método deveria ser implementado como:

```
public virtual JsonResult Salvar(TViewModel model) { ... }
```

E o método deve ser chamado através de Ajax.

Se a ideia é realmente modificar o estado atual da página, você pode redirecionar para o mesmo documento, mas a abertura da modal para exibir, por exemplo, mensagens de validação, não é garantida:

```
public virtual ActionResult Salvar(TViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (model.Operacao.Equals("I"))
            Inserir(model);
        else
            Atualizar(model);                

        return RedirectToAction(NmView);
    }

    return View(model); // Troque aqui.
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas. Na verdade quando o ModelState for válido, a Modal será fechada e a página principal carregada. Quando ocorrer um erro que o estado da página deve ser mantido e a modal carregada. Neste cenário ainda é mais recomendável retornar JsonResult?

Comment: Sim. Você terá que fazer um Ajax que esperará um JSON como retorno. Caso o retorno seja um JSON com sucesso, o estado da página muda. Caso contrário, o JavaScript deve emitir uma mensagem de erro.